# How to find which machine is running an IIS website?

Tags: iis, windows-10

There's a website running on a machine somewhere in my company. I know the external URL, and can visit the site. (e.g. `madeupurl.mycompany.com`) Doing an nslookup on the URL shows an external IP address. I'd like to remote into the machine to make some changes, but I don't know the computer name or internal IP address.

Is there a straightforward way to find out?

Comment: Ask someone who knows (hopefully there is someone...) or wireshark / tcpdump your way through your network.

Comment: Yeah, thankfully I was able to find someone who knew (the person who originally set it up has moved on), but I'm posting in hope of a general solution as I'm sure it'll come up again.

Comment: You can probably make the assumption it's listening on port 80/443/8080 and I assume it's a server class/role so it's likely to be up most of the time.  If you view the content of the site externally then you know what a response looks like to a given request, even if it's the title of a given page on the site.  So you could script a GET request to every computer on port 80/443/8080, looking for a response that matches the external site.  I assume there aren't that many webservers so you can probably make a short list given a first pass of port probing with maybe a IP range for servers, etc...

Comment: With that information you cannot never know what you wanted. It is always a task of network administrators to tell where the server is. Keep in mind that if you can tell the machine name from web pages/requests, then it is an information leakage.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a network admin to capture the traffic on the firewall while browsing the site to see where it is routed to/from.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use a utility that allows you to conduct a port scan of the network, specifically for port 80 and port 443 (HTTP and HTTPS respectively). Nmap would be an example of such a tool.

If multiple web servers exist on the network that are all listening to port 80 and port 443 (common in PATed networks), then your only solution from there would be to use something like Wireshark or another protocol analyzer to conduct a scan of the packets coming in and out of the network in order to detect packets related to the web traffic for that particular website or you could connect to each server listening to those ports and check what site(s) it's hosting.